Mellin Inversion Theorem for integral transforms with different kernels.
I am studying the Mellin inversion theorem and its applications in various integral transforms. I understand that the Mellin transform uses the power function $ x^{s-1} $ as a kernel and that the inversion process involves a similar kernel $ x^{-s} $.
Similarly, in the Laplace transform, the kernel is the exponential function $ e^{-sx} $, and the inverse transform involves $ e^{sx} $.
My questions are:

Proper Terminology: What is the proper mathematical term for these "kernels" or "weight" functions $ x^{-s} $ (in Mellin) and $ e^{-sx} $ (in Laplace)?

Generalizations of the Mellin Inversion Theorem: Are there generalizations of the Mellin inversion theorem for other integral transforms that use different kernels? If so, what are some examples? For instance, if I have an integral that looks exactly like an inverse Laplace transform but with the kernel $ e^{-s/x} $ instead, i.e.,
$$
   f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F(s) e^{-s/x} \, ds,
   $$
how do I find the corresponding forward integral transform?

Defining New Integral Transforms: Is it possible to define new integral transforms by choosing an appropriate kernel? Under what conditions would the inversion theorem hold for these new transforms? Specifically, I am interested in the methods to find the forward transform given an inverse transform of the form
$$
   f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} F(s) K(s,x) \, ds,
   $$
where $ K(s,x) $ is a given kernel (e.g., $ e^{s/x} $ or $ c^{1/x} $).


I’m looking for rigorous conditions under which such generalized inversion theorems apply and examples of existing transforms where this is the case.
Additional Details
To clarify my current understanding, here are the standard formulas for the Mellin and Laplace transforms and their inverses:

Mellin Transform:
$$
  \mathcal{M}\{f(x); s\} = F(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} f(x) \, dx
  $$

Inverse Mellin Transform:
$$
  f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} x^{-s} F(s) \, ds
  $$

Laplace Transform:
$$
  \mathcal{L}\{f(t); s\} = F(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} f(t) \, dt
  $$

Inverse Laplace Transform:
$$
  f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} e^{st} F(s) \, ds
  $$


Thank you for your help!

Yes! and I am particularly interested in the case when this "kernel" is $k(s,t)=e^{s/t}$, which is like an inverted Fourier transform or so.
